# Google Vision: Extract confidence of each word after extracting whole text using full_text_annotation.text

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I am using

```
def detect_document(path):
     client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

     with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

     image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

     response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)

     text = response.full_text_annotation.text
     text = text.casefold()
     text = text.replace('(','')
     text = text.replace(')','')
     text = text.replace(':','')
     text = text.replace('.','')

     return text
```

to extract following text from an application form filled with handwriting

```
a bank challan
bank branch abc mute deposit id 005saetm-0055 deposit date 14 ml 19
b personal information use capital letters and leave spaces between words
name muhammad hanif tiid
father's name muhammad yaqoob tiittitttt
computerized nic no 44 303-5214 345-3
d d m m y y y y
gender male age in years 22 date of birth  4-08-1999
domicile district mirpuskhas contact no 0333-7072258
please do not mention converted no
postal address anmol book depo naukot taluka jhuddo disstti mps
sindh
are you government servant yes
if yes, please attach noc
no
✓
religion muslim
✓
non-muslim o
c academic information
intermediate/hssc eng mirpuskhas bise match b 2016
matric/ssc seience bisemirpurkhang match a 2014
d any other certifications/diploma/professional degrees shorthand, dit, cit etc
name
le
```

Then using regex patterns to get

[image]

Now I want to create log for all the processing for each field

```
<name>

<origin>

muhammad hanif tiid 

</origin>

<originscore>

78.2

</originscore>

<final>

muhammad hanif

</final>

<corrections>

4

</corrections>

</name>
```

For that I need **confidence score**. I don't know how to get confidence score for such parsed fields. I tried to get confidence of each extracted word, like

```
A: 0.9900000095367432
.: 0.9900000095367432
Bank: 0.9900000095367432
Challan: 0.9900000095367432
Bank: 0.9900000095367432
Branch: 0.9900000095367432
ABC: 0.9900000095367432
mute: 0.6700000166893005
Deposit: 0.8500000238418579
ID: 0.8100000023841858
005SAETM: 0.6499999761581421
-: 0.2800000011920929
0055: 0.8500000238418579
Deposit: 0.9200000166893005
Date: 0.9900000095367432
14: 0.6399999856948853
ml: 0.5400000214576721
19: 0.550000011920929
B: 0.9900000095367432
.: 0.9900000095367432
Personal: 0.9900000095367432
Information: 0.9900000095367432
:: 0.9900000095367432
Use: 0.9399999976158142
CAPITAL: 0.9900000095367432
letters: 0.9900000095367432
and: 0.9900000095367432
leave: 0.9900000095367432
spaces: 0.9900000095367432
between: 0.9900000095367432
words: 0.9900000095367432
.: 0.9900000095367432
Name: 0.9900000095367432
:: 0.9800000190734863
MUHAMMAD: 0.9599999785423279
HANIF: 0.9399999976158142
TIID: 0.46000000834465027
Father: 0.9900000095367432
': 0.9800000190734863
```

which doesn't solve the problem.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this snippet of code:

```
text = response.full_text_annotation.text
     text = text.casefold()
     text = text.replace('(','')
     text = text.replace(')','')
     text = text.replace(':','')
     text = text.replace('.','')

     return text
```

with:

```
for page in response.full_text_annotation.pages:
    for block in page.blocks:
        for paragraph in block.paragraphs:
            for word in paragraph.words:
                word_text = ''.join([
                    symbol.text for symbol in word.symbols
                ])
                print('{}: {}'.format(
                    word_text, word.confidence))
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asWIZ.png)

Comment: I have also used same logic to get confidence of each extracted word as I've shown above, but it doesn't solve the problem. I need get confidence score of each phrase rather than individual words, for example CNIC, which may contain '44601' '-' '6622831' '-' '3'.

Comment: I don't think getting confidence score by phrase is currently possible. The hierarchy of an OCR extracted text structure is like this: TextAnnotation -> Page -> Block -> Paragraph -> Word -> Symbol

Comment: That is true as far as I know. Any alternative solution to this problem?